# what's difference between Animation and Animatable in flutter

Tags: flutter

i read

> A Tween inherits from Animatable, not from Animation. An Animatable, like Animation, doesn’t have to output double. For example, ColorTween specifies a progression between two colors.

in [Tween description](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/animations/tutorial#tween) but i can't undrestand wht's that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is that Animatable<T> can produce values which not need to be type of *double*. This values produced based on double values inputed to Tween. So, you can change values of Offset, or Color from blue to green, or some other type <T>. Input values from 0.0 to 1.0 -> output from Blue to Green

Answer (score 1):

Flutter represents an animation as a value that changes over a given duration. That value may be of any type e.g double, Color etc. It is essentially a range of values that are interpolated over a specified time. The most common use is to animate properties like opacity, position, or scale over time.

Most widgets that perform an animation receive the `Animation` object as a parameter, from which they read the current value of the animation and to which they listen for changes to that value. By default, an `AnimationController` increases its animation value linearly from 0.0 to 1.0 over a given duration.

`Animation` itself doesn't define the type or range of values it represents. It is a raw representation of the progression of time. If you want to animate different types of values( e.g Colors or Shapes). you need to use `Animatable`

`Animatable` is a more abstract concept that represents something that can be animated between two values. These values do not need to be of type double. It is often used for animations involving complex types, such as Colors, Shapes, or Other custom Objects. To use an `Animatable` you wrap it around an `Animation`. This combination allows you to define how the animation values are interpolated between the begin and end states. `Tween` is a common implementation of `Animatable` that represents a range of values and interpolates between them. Example `ColorTween` is an implementation of `Animatable<Color>` that animates between two colors